# How I can turn PET plastic into PETG?

Tags: filament, extrusion, petg, pet, chemistry

With a friend, we managed to successfully make ABS filament and print with it (even though we sold a couple of spools) now we want to turn our attention to PET. The problem is that it's really hard to extrude properly into filament, so we are wondering how to turn it into PETG (I don't care if it's not possible to do at home, we are creating a brand of filaments, so we need to know how it's done to then attempt to make it (like a list of steps)). If it's not possible to add it, do you know any other polymers that can be mixed to achieve similar properties?

Comment: This sounds more like a Chemistry.SE question. Hopefully, those more experienced can provide additional input.

Comment: You didn't say what you plan to make it from - presumably pellets, and if so, you get PETG pellets. I don't think you can just mix things at pellet-size scale and get copolymers out. However, PET is a vastly superior printing material to PETG, so I'd like to suggest a frame challenge to figure out what problem you're hitting producing filament from it, and solve that. There are very few manufacturers selling PET filament right now (afaik only Fusion Filaments in the US, and a few here and there in other countries), and if you can figure out how to do it well, you'd have very few competitors.